# jQuery: custom horizontal accordion style showcase issue

Tags: jquery, accordion, carousel

Im trying to create a custom horizontal accordion style showcase. In terms of actual functionality, i have the framework (which can be seen here):

http://www.jsfiddle.net/adrianjacob/UdUus/

However my main bug bear (and the clients) is that if you look at the right hand side of the last li, there is always slight movement/flickering as the widths animate up and down.

Ideally I want it to appear smooth with no dodgy movement on the last item as other things resize. Any idea how I can achieve this?

A.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it another way: http://www.jsfiddle.net/elektronikLexikon/4mBYE/

The `.promo`s always have 200px width and are moved to the left or right with this script:

```
$("#promo div").mouseenter(function() {
    i = parseInt($("#promo div").index(this));
    $(this).animate({
        left: i*50
    }, 500).nextAll().each(function(j) {
        $(this).animate({
            left: (i+j)*50+200
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

(in the jsFiddle, I use hoverIntent, too)

Comment: Hi. I like the idea but if i start hovering over 3,4 or 5 for example i lose other items (all items always need to be visible)

Comment: should be fixed now. Just do the same with prevAll() as with nextAll()